# Can I run multiple services in same go on same ECS fargate Cluster

Tags: service, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a ECS fargate cluster up and running and it has 1 service and 1 task definition attached to it.
The task definition already has 2 container images described.This cluster is up and running.
Can I create a new service and for another application and configure it with this Existing ECS cluster.
If yes, will both the service run simultaneously.

Comment: Yes you can multiple services inside the same fargate cluster. I have done this setup for a project

Answer (score 0):

From the AWS Documentation in regards Amazon ECS Clusters

> An Amazon ECS cluster is a logical grouping of tasks or services. Your
> tasks and services are run on infrastructure that is registered to a
> cluster.

So I believe, you should be able to run multiple services in a cluster that is attached to its related task definition in the ECS.

Source Documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/clusters.html